# Logback log location

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I'm using SLF4J with java for logs, i know how to save to specific location, but I want that the log will create under the jar running folder.

How could I set it in the `logback.xml`?
I tried to not defined the `DEV_HOME` value or with `./`, but it didn't create the log under the jar location.
this is my current configuration:

```
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="user.home" />

<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<logger name="com.FAM" level="debug"
        additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</logger>

<root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing

```
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="user.home" />
```

set the value of DEV_HOME to the string "user.home". What you probably want is

```
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="${user.home}" />
```

Note the **${}** above.

Also the syntax for size and time based had been [simplified](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy). However, the old syntax with SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP that you are using is still valid.

To find the path to the folder where a given jar file is located, here is sample code to get you going. Note that class C is assumed to be available and located in one of the jar files you are looking for.

```
String cClassAsResource = C.class.getName().replace('.', '/')+".class";
System.out.println(cClassAsResource);
URL pathToClassAsURL = C.class.getClassLoader().getResource(cClassAsResource);

// Assume that pathToClassAsURL.toString() begins with "jar:file:/"
String prefix = "jar:file:/";

String jarPathPlusTrailingClass = pathToClassAsURL.toString().substring(prefix.length());
System.out.println(jarPathPlusTrailingClass);
int indexOfExclamationMark = jarPathPlusTrailingClass.indexOf('!');
String jarPath = jarPathPlusTrailingClass.substring(0, indexOfExclamationMark);
System.out.println(jarPath);
```

For variables that need custom computation, logback allows you to [define them on the fly](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingPropsOnTheFly).

Comment: Hi, thanks it save now the log under the user path, but how I could create the log under the jar running folder?

Comment: See modified answer above.